# Testing a shopify_app ruby request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec-rails, shopify-app

I'm trying to test a controller method through a Rspec:

```
RSpec.describe 'HomeController', type: :request do
```

I configured a login function to enter into the restricted controller's actions:

```
def shopify_login(shop)
  OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true
  OmniAuth.config.add_mock(:shopify, provider: 'shopify', uid: shop.shopify_domain,
  credentials: { token: shop.shopify_token })

  Rails.application.env_config['omniauth.auth'] = OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:shopify]
  Rails.application.env_config['omniauth.params'] = { shop: shop.shopify_domain }
  Rails.application.env_config['jwt.shopify_domain'] = shop.shopify_domain

  post '/auth/shopify'
  follow_redirect!
end
```

In my **config/initializer/omniauth.rb** file I have:

```
 configuration = ShopifyApp::OmniAuthConfiguration.new(env['omniauth.strategy'],
                                       Rack::Request.new(env))
 configuration.build_options
```

The code works fine on the browser but when I run the spec I'm getting:

```
 <ActionDispatch::Request::Session:0x2a440 not yet loaded>
```

digging a little I see in the file:

```
 /.rvm/ruby-3.0.2/gems/shopify_app-18.0.2/lib/shopify_app/omniauth/omniauth_configuration.rb
```

the method:

```
def shopify_auth_params
  puts "## SHOPIFY AUTH PARAMS strategy.session ##>>  #{strategy.session.inspect} "

  strategy.session['shopify.omniauth_params']&.with_indifferent_access
end
```

so trying to get "strategy.session" value is causing the "not yet loaded" message.

As far as I understand the:

```
RSpec.describe 'HomeController', type: :request do
```

test won't create a Rails session until a request is made. So, I'm trying to understand how I could "launch" manually a session?

**UPDATE**

It works with the ominiauth initializer like:

```
  setup: lambda { |env|
    strategy = env['omniauth.strategy']

    shop = if strategy.request.params['shop']
             "https://#{strategy.request.params['shop']}"
           else
             ''
           end

    env['omniauth.strategy'].options[:client_options][:site] = shop
  }
```

Besides, check that your shopify_app initializer holds:

```
config.allow_jwt_authentication = true
config.allow_cookie_authentication = Rails.env.test?
```

Comment: Did you manage to figure this one out? I'm stuck on the same thing more or less, trying to follow: https://philstories.medium.com/omniauth-integration-testing-with-rails-6-shopify-app-9e4a77084827

Comment: Yeah, I updated the section.

Comment: Thank you - I'll give it a go this morning. :)